# Android adb doesnt recognize Samsung Galaxy S (I9000) on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: android, windows-7, 64-bit, adb

Has anyone been successful with hooking up a Samsung Galaxy S (I9000) with ADB running on Win 7? Links to already existing threads or tutorials related to this would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done it - no problems Win7/64Bit. Can't give you an exact link, but can tell you how to get the right driver. Go to the [Samsung Mobile Innovator site](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/platform.main.do?platformId=1) and a little way down is a green button titled "Download: SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe".

This simply worked for me for both both the Galaxy-Tab and the Epic.

Edit: [Exact Link](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows)

Comment: yeah no idea why you need special drivers, but you do.  Also if you install them BEFORE Installing the regular ones you will never be able to get the regular ones installed.  makes me want to switch to linux/mac so sick of driver issues.

Answer (score 6):

To make it work just update driver > Browse my computer > Look for where you have your android sdk installed and select the extras>google>usb driver folder. Then go ahead with the installation as normal. You device should be detected. Just did this 2 minutes ago.

EDIT: Oh and make sure to be using the latest sdk and drivers.

Comment: Thahks this work for me after 2 days googling and reading forums

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with Samsung Skyrocket (AT&T) and I fixed it by installing Samsung Kies software (http://www.samsung.com/ca/kies/index.html)

Crazy, I know. It should have been much more straightforward. My Mac had no issues and Windows 7 was full of it!