# Samsung Galaxy S adb driver details?

Tags: android, driver, adb

I'm in a pickle. I live in Korea and teach English but am developing an android app. I want to test on my Samsung Galaxy S.  Can't find an adb driver for it  as the only drivers I could find are the US versions of the device.  Anyone got driver details for this device?

Comment: This is not really a programming question. It might be better asked on SuperUser, or even straight to Samsung support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446256/android-adb-doesnt-recognize-samsung-galaxy-s-i9000-on-windows-7-64-bit) but the link is dead. However you can find the American drivers [here](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/platform.main.do?platformId=1) and the Chinese drivers [here](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cn/) (I don't think there is a difference).

Comment: if my answer helped you find the drivers make sure to make this answer as correct so other people can find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

**[UNIVERSAL ADB DRIVER](http://adbdriver.com)**

**drivers for any android device**

I have thesame issue before but i solved it easily by just following this steps:

*connect your android phone in a debugging mode
(to enable debugging mode goto settings scroll down About Phone scroll down tap seven times Build Number and it will automatically enable developer option turn on developer options and check USB debugging)

download Universal ADB Driver Installer

*choose Adb Driver Installer (Universal)

*install it 
*it will automatically detect your android device(**any kind of brand**)

*chose the device and install

Answer (score 1):

I only found this USB driver for Windows.

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Android-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem installing Samsung Kies!