# ADB not recognizing samsung galaxy S?

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile

USB debugging is enabled,my mac recognizes that the phone is connected but eclipse doesn't list it as a device and i can't test my application. I am using a macbook air with OSX and Eclipse does not recognize my device? I am aware some people have this problem with mac but i cannot find a solution.

Comment: Duplicate of [can't get ADB to recognize my galaxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376475/cant-get-adb-to-recognize-my-galaxy). Please do a search first before posting new questions; the post I linked to was found by searching on `adb galaxy` using the `android` tag. Avoiding duplicates keeps the clutter down and helps keep SO a useful resource. Thanks. :) You might also find [Samsung Galaxy S adb driver details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542923/samsung-galaxy-s-adb-driver-details) useful.

Comment: no no no practically irrrelevant, i said i was using a mac, not a windows pc, this is very different! Because it works right away with a pc

Comment: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/platform.main.do?platformId=1 That is the link to samsung driver download. It is under Resource type: tools. It states that it is windows only though. I'd guess if kies doesn't enable the adb for you then you may be S.O.L. with that device and development machine.

Answer (score 3):

I had installed the "**google-usb-driver**" package(present in the extras subsection of SDK manager) and also had **debugging enabled** on my Samsung S3. Yet eclipse/adb was not able to recognize the device.

To solve this problem on **windows**, I installed **kies**. I can now see a new device called "samsung android phone" in the list of devices(in device manager).

Windows(7/2008) by default does not have the driver and this can be got from a kies setup. Now my device manager is showing 2 devices:

1. Portable devices > GT-I93XX (already had this before kies was installed)
2. Samsung Android Phone > Samsung **Android ADB Interface**. (this was new after kies installation)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the USB cable can be at fault, I have found the cable from the Kindle to be more reliable then those supplied by Samsung or Motorola (for reasons unknown to me!).

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to install some Samsung driver software. On windows at least the adb driver comes bundled with their kies desktop software. I'd start by finding mac version of that and installing it.

Also "Samsung Galaxy S" is not a specific device. This is a marketing name that has been applied to half a dozen or more devices total worldwide. It may be helpful in some cases (perhaps it doesn't matter here, but it could) to specify which specific piece of hardware you are working with.

Do any other brand devices work correctly?